# Gmail shows a different contact name depending on how contact sent email?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

So, this is something odd I recently starting seeing. I have someone in my contacts, and they've emailed me without problems over the years. Recently however, rather than showing their name as 'First Name Last Name', like it has done for years, some of their emails are just showing up with a single character as the contact name in my inbox.

So instead of 'Bob Smith' (Not the real name), it's showing up as just 'S'.

Digging into things a big more, I downloaded the original emails and took a look and I see these in the original messages:

```
Bob Smith <notTheRealEmail@aol.com> Using iPhone Mail (20A380)
S <notTheRealEmail@aol.com> Using WebService/1.1.20863 aolwebmail
```

So it "appears" (to my small brain) that this has to do with something between sending an email from their phone versus sending an email through some sort of web client. But why does Gmail care?

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this so that they show up consistently? The email in question is in my contacts list.

Comment: Can you clarify if the headers are from the  same message or from two different messages.

Comment: This is likely configured on the senders mail client. https://help.aol.com/articles/aol-mail-mail-settings